# Телеграмм бот проверка на сообщение от пользователя

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, lua

Как на языке Lua сделать проверку на сообщение от пользователя в телеграмм боте?

Answer (score 0):

[Документация telegram-bot-lua](https://github.com/wrxck/telegram-bot-lua)

```
function api.on_message(message)
    if message.text
    and message.text:match('ping')
    then
        api.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            'pong'
        )
    end
end
```

[Документация lua-telegram-bot](https://github.com/ldb/lua-telegram-bot)

```
extension.onTextReceive = function (msg)
    print("New Message by " .. msg.from.first_name)

    if (msg.text == "/start") then
        bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "Hello there \nMy name is " .. bot.first_name)
    elseif (msg.text == "ping") then
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "pong!")
    else
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "I am just an example")
    end
end
```